# Yocto ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'core'. Close matches: pcre

Tags: yocto

I get the following error when trying to do a bitbake core image minimal: ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'core'. Close matches: pcre  When doing an Internet search nothing comes up.  If anyone knows what this error relates to, I would be grateful to know.  Also if anyone knows of a good beginner tutorial for Yocto, please share.  The local.conf file is below:

```
#
# This file is your local configuration file and is where all local user settings
# are placed. The comments in this file give some guide to the options a new user
# to the system might want to change but pretty much any configuration option can
# be set in this file. More adventurous users can look at
# local.conf.sample.extended which contains other examples of configuration which
# can be placed in this file but new users likely won't need any of them
# initially. There's also site.conf.sample which contains examples of site specific
# information such as proxy server addresses.
#
# Lines starting with the '#' character are commented out and in some cases the
# default values are provided as comments to show people example syntax. Enabling
# the option is a question of removing the # character and making any change to the
# variable as required.

#
# Machine Selection
#
# You need to select a specific machine to target the build with. There are a selection
# of emulated machines available which can boot and run in the QEMU emulator:
#
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64"
#MACHINE ?= "qemumips"
#MACHINE ?= "qemumips64"
#MACHINE ?= "qemuppc"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86"
#MACHINE ?= "qemux86-64"
#
# There are also the following hardware board target machines included for 
# demonstration purposes:
#
#MACHINE ?= "beaglebone-yocto"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86"
#MACHINE ?= "genericx86-64"
#MACHINE ?= "edgerouter"
#
# This sets the default machine to be qemux86-64 if no other machine is selected:
MACHINE ??= "qemux86-64"
BB_NUMBER_THREADS ?= "4"
PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j 2"
# These are some of the more commonly used values. Looking at the files in the
# meta/conf/machine directory, or the conf/machine directory of any additional layers
# you add in will show all the available machines.

#
# Where to place downloads
#
# During a first build the system will download many different source code tarballs
# from various upstream projects. This can take a while, particularly if your network
# connection is slow. These are all stored in DL_DIR. When wiping and rebuilding you
# can preserve this directory to speed up this part of subsequent builds. This directory
# is safe to share between multiple builds on the same machine too.
#
# The default is a downloads directory under TOPDIR which is the build directory.
#
#DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/downloads"

#
# Where to place shared-state files
#
# BitBake has the capability to accelerate builds based on previously built output.
# This is done using "shared state" files which can be thought of as cache objects
# and this option determines where those files are placed.
#
# You can wipe out TMPDIR leaving this directory intact and the build would regenerate
# from these files if no changes were made to the configuration. If changes were made
# to the configuration, only shared state files where the state was still valid would
# be used (done using checksums).
#
# The default is a sstate-cache directory under TOPDIR.
#
#SSTATE_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/sstate-cache"

#
# Where to place the build output
#
# This option specifies where the bulk of the building work should be done and
# where BitBake should place its temporary files and output. Keep in mind that
# this includes the extraction and compilation of many applications and the toolchain
# which can use Gigabytes of hard disk space.
#
# The default is a tmp directory under TOPDIR.
#
#TMPDIR = "${TOPDIR}/tmp"

#
# Default policy config
#
# The distribution setting controls which policy settings are used as defaults.
# The default value is fine for general Yocto project use, at least initially.
# Ultimately when creating custom policy, people will likely end up subclassing 
# these defaults.
#
DISTRO ?= "poky"
# As an example of a subclass there is a "bleeding" edge policy configuration
# where many versions are set to the absolute latest code from the upstream 
# source control systems. This is just mentioned here as an example, its not
# useful to most new users.
# DISTRO ?= "poky-bleeding"

#
# Package Management configuration
#
# This variable lists which packaging formats to enable. Multiple package backends
# can be enabled at once and the first item listed in the variable will be used
# to generate the root filesystems.
# Options are:
#  - 'package_deb' for debian style deb files
#  - 'package_ipk' for ipk files are used by opkg (a debian style embedded package manager)
#  - 'package_rpm' for rpm style packages
# E.g.: PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm package_deb package_ipk"
# OE-Core defaults to ipkg, whilst Poky defaults to rpm:
# PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"

#
# SDK target architecture
#
# This variable specifies the architecture to build SDK items for and means
# you can build the SDK packages for architectures other than the machine you are
# running the build on (i.e. building i686 packages on an x86_64 host).
# Supported values are i686, x86_64, aarch64
#SDKMACHINE ?= "i686"

#
# Extra image configuration defaults
#
# The EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES variable allows extra packages to be added to the generated
# images. Some of these options are added to certain image types automatically. The
# variable can contain the following options:
#  "dbg-pkgs"       - add -dbg packages for all installed packages
#                     (adds symbol information for debugging/profiling)
#  "src-pkgs"       - add -src packages for all installed packages
#                     (adds source code for debugging)
#  "dev-pkgs"       - add -dev packages for all installed packages
#                     (useful if you want to develop against libs in the image)
#  "ptest-pkgs"     - add -ptest packages for all ptest-enabled packages
#                     (useful if you want to run the package test suites)
#  "tools-sdk"      - add development tools (gcc, make, pkgconfig etc.)
#  "tools-debug"    - add debugging tools (gdb, strace)
#  "eclipse-debug"  - add Eclipse remote debugging support
#  "tools-profile"  - add profiling tools (oprofile, lttng, valgrind)
#  "tools-testapps" - add useful testing tools (ts_print, aplay, arecord etc.)
#  "debug-tweaks"   - make an image suitable for development
#                     e.g. ssh root access has a blank password
# There are other application targets that can be used here too, see
# meta/classes-recipe/image.bbclass and
# meta/classes-recipe/core-image.bbclass for more details.
# We default to enabling the debugging tweaks.
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"

#
# Additional image features
#
# The following is a list of additional classes to use when building images which
# enable extra features. Some available options which can be included in this variable
# are:
#   - 'buildstats' collect build statistics
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"

#
# Runtime testing of images
#
# The build system can test booting virtual machine images under qemu (an emulator)
# after any root filesystems are created and run tests against those images. It can also
# run tests against any SDK that are built. To enable this uncomment these lines.
# See meta/classes-recipe/test{image,sdk}.bbclass for further details.
#IMAGE_CLASSES += "testimage testsdk"
#TESTIMAGE_AUTO:qemuall = "1"

#
# Interactive shell configuration
#
# Under certain circumstances the system may need input from you and to do this it
# can launch an interactive shell. It needs to do this since the build is
# multithreaded and needs to be able to handle the case where more than one parallel
# process may require the user's attention. The default is iterate over the available
# terminal types to find one that works.
#
# Examples of the occasions this may happen are when resolving patches which cannot
# be applied, to use the devshell or the kernel menuconfig
#
# Supported values are auto, gnome, xfce, rxvt, screen, konsole (KDE 3.x only), none
# Note: currently, Konsole support only works for KDE 3.x due to the way
# newer Konsole versions behave
#OE_TERMINAL = "auto"
# By default disable interactive patch resolution (tasks will just fail instead):
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"

#
# Disk Space Monitoring during the build
#
# Monitor the disk space during the build. If there is less that 1GB of space or less
# than 100K inodes in any key build location (TMPDIR, DL_DIR, SSTATE_DIR), gracefully
# shutdown the build. If there is less than 100MB or 1K inodes, perform a hard halt
# of the build. The reason for this is that running completely out of space can corrupt
# files and damages the build in ways which may not be easily recoverable.
# It's necessary to monitor /tmp, if there is no space left the build will fail
# with very exotic errors.
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    HALT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,/tmp,10M,1K"

#
# Shared-state files from other locations
#
# As mentioned above, shared state files are prebuilt cache data objects which can be
# used to accelerate build time. This variable can be used to configure the system
# to search other mirror locations for these objects before it builds the data itself.
#
# This can be a filesystem directory, or a remote url such as https or ftp. These
# would contain the sstate-cache results from previous builds (possibly from other
# machines). This variable works like fetcher MIRRORS/PREMIRRORS and points to the
# cache locations to check for the shared objects.
# NOTE: if the mirror uses the same structure as SSTATE_DIR, you need to add PATH
# at the end as shown in the examples below. This will be substituted with the
# correct path within the directory structure.
#SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "\
#file://.* https://someserver.tld/share/sstate/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH \
#file://.* file:///some/local/dir/sstate/PATH"

#
# Yocto Project SState Mirror
#
# The Yocto Project has prebuilt artefacts available for its releases, you can enable
# use of these by uncommenting the following lines. This will mean the build uses
# the network to check for artefacts at the start of builds, which does slow it down
# equally, it will also speed up the builds by not having to build things if they are
# present in the cache. It assumes you can download something faster than you can build it
# which will depend on your network.
# Note: For this to work you also need hash-equivalence passthrough to the matching server
#
#BB_HASHSERVE_UPSTREAM = "hashserv.yocto.io:8687"
#SSTATE_MIRRORS ?= "file://.* http://sstate.yoctoproject.org/all/PATH;downloadfilename=PATH"

#
# Qemu configuration
#
# By default native qemu will build with a builtin VNC server where graphical output can be
# seen. The line below enables the SDL UI frontend too.
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
# By default libsdl2-native will be built, if you want to use your host's libSDL instead of 
# the minimal libsdl built by libsdl2-native then uncomment the ASSUME_PROVIDED line below.
#ASSUME_PROVIDED += "libsdl2-native"

# You can also enable the Gtk UI frontend, which takes somewhat longer to build, but adds
# a handy set of menus for controlling the emulator.
#PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " gtk+"

#
# Hash Equivalence
#
# Enable support for automatically running a local hash equivalence server and
# instruct bitbake to use a hash equivalence aware signature generator. Hash
# equivalence improves reuse of sstate by detecting when a given sstate
# artifact can be reused as equivalent, even if the current task hash doesn't
# match the one that generated the artifact.
#
# A shared hash equivalent server can be set with "<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>" format
#
#BB_HASHSERVE = "auto"
#BB_SIGNATURE_HANDLER = "OEEquivHash"

#
# Memory Resident Bitbake
#
# Bitbake's server component can stay in memory after the UI for the current command
# has completed. This means subsequent commands can run faster since there is no need
# for bitbake to reload cache files and so on. Number is in seconds, after which the
# server will shut down.
#
#BB_SERVER_TIMEOUT = "60"

# CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/ changes incompatibly and is used to
# track the version of this file when it was generated. This can safely be ignored if
# this doesn't mean anything to you.
CONF_VERSION = "2"
```

I can't seem to find the error when doing a search.  If anyone know what causes the error or a different local.conf file, I would be very grateful.  Thank you, Harry

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are trying to build `core` instead of `core-image-minimal`. But you didn't even post the full error message unfortunately.

You can check available targets with `bitbake -s` and `grep` for what you need. For example `core` is not an available target, hence bitbake complains "nothing provides core".

Also, look at https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ and start working on the intro section. Bitbake is a tool with a steep learning curve, I encourage you to invest a few hours there.